# scala classloaders confusion

Tags: scala, classloader

Please consider the following test program (using scala 2.9.0.1)

```
object test
{
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    println(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.getResource("toto"))
    println(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("toto"))
    println(classOf[Object].getClassLoader)
  }
}
```

I compile it and run it with "-cp /tmp" containing a file "toto", and I get the following output:

```
null
file:/tmp/toto
null
```

=> the system classloader does not contain the classpath

=> the Object class has no classloader!

Am I missing something there or is it a (big) bug in scala?!

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second null is explained by [java.lang.Class#getClassLoader()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29)

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use
>   null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
>   null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.

So, this is why `classOf[Object].getClassLoader` returns null, it's loaded by the bootstrap classloader (it is in rt.jar, more specifically, it is in a jar which is in $JAVA_HOME/lib).

The first null is harder to explain. It seems that Scala leaves the system classloader as-is, and only adds the options -cp to it's own classloader (ScalaClassLoader in scala/util/ClassLoader.scala).

Using the following:

```
object Test {
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    println(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader)
    println(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
    println(classOf[Object].getClassLoader)
  }
}
```

and running it with:

```
$ scala -cp /temp Test
```

we get the following output:

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
URLClassLoader(
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/resources.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/rt.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/jsse.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/jce.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/charsets.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
  file:/C:/developpement/utils/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
  file:/C:/DEVELO~1/scala/SCALA-~1.1/bin/../lib/jline.jar
  file:/C:/DEVELO~1/scala/SCALA-~1.1/bin/../lib/scala-compiler.jar
  file:/C:/DEVELO~1/scala/SCALA-~1.1/bin/../lib/scala-dbc.jar
  file:/C:/DEVELO~1/scala/SCALA-~1.1/bin/../lib/scala-library.jar
  file:/C:/DEVELO~1/scala/SCALA-~1.1/bin/../lib/scala-swing.jar
  file:/C:/DEVELO~1/scala/SCALA-~1.1/bin/../lib/scalap.jar
  file:/C:/temp/
)

null
```

So the System classloader is left untouched, but the Scala classloader gets the items from -cp added to it.

Moral of the story: don't use the system classloader in Scala if you want to access resources from the classpath.

EDIT: Ok, I've investigated this a bit more, and scala.bat is executing the following command line (under pure Windows, shortened for readability)

```
java.exe -Xmx256M -Xms32M -Dscala.home="xxx" -cp "libsfromscalahome" scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  -cp /temp Test
```

So the -cp option from the command line is only being passed as an option to MainGenericRunner, **not** the java. I believe, from looking at the code, that under unix you can specify the -toolcp option to scala to get something included in the java classpath. Something like (totally untested):

```
$ scala -toolcp /temp Test
```

This option isn't available in scala.bat. Which means if you're working under windows, you'll have to get the resources using

```
println(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("toto"))
```

I couldn't find an issue in the [Scala Lang Issues](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa), but if it's a problem for you, raise an issue and submit a fix. I'm sure they'll be thrilled :-)

EDIT: I have raised this as issue [SI 5062 -toolcp should be available on windows, in the scala.bat](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5062), and provided a pull request for it on [github](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/107).

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia's classloader article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader):

> The system class loader loads code found on java.class.path, which
>   maps to the system CLASSPATH variable.

Not sure about the second null though. Maybe someone else can clear that up.